# How to get the bottom most div to stop floating at the footer

Tags: html, css

I have three divs floating on the right and the position is fixed. I would like the bottom most div to stop when it reaches the footer; however, it goes behind the footer and gets covered. I have been trying to fix this for some time but can't figure it out.. The footer is set at position: relative and the width is set too 100%.

```css
    .sidebar-sticky {
            margin-right: 9px;
            position: fixed;
            margin-left: 800px;
        }

        .sidebar-sticky2 {
            margin-right: 9px;
            position: fixed;
            margin-left: 800px;
            margin-top: 350px;
        }

        .sidebar-sticky3 {
            margin-right: 9px;
            margin-left: -340px;
            margin-top: 605px;
            position: fixed;
        }
```

```html
    <!-- Office Reservation -->
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_In_Out" runat="server">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="office-reservation">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">OFFICE RESERVATION</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <%--<div class="divider-line" style="width: 90px; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; text-align: center; margin: 0px 50px 0px 70px;"></div>--%>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #444;"><b>In</b></label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="textarea-form">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchDateFrom" CssClass="form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding: 3px;"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchTimeFrom" CssClass="form-control" Width="145" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SearchTimeFrom" CssClass="form-control text-right" Width="145" Height="35" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="padding: 3px; width: 20px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="padding-left: 20px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #444;"><b>Out</b></label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchDateTo" CssClass="form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="padding: 3px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchTimeTo" CssClass="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" Width="145" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SearchTimeTo" CssClass="form-control" Width="145" Height="35" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="padding: 3px; width:20px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wigdet_input_box" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Reserve" runat="server" Text="RESERVE" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Width="50%" OnClick="btn_Reserve_Time_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <!-- QUICK CONTACT FORM -->
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_Question" runat="server">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="sidebar-sticky2">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">QUESTIONS ?</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Email" CssClass="form-control" Width="145" Font-Size="Small" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="padding: 3px"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Message" TextMode="multiline" Rows="3" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="form-control" class="contact-message" Style="width: 100%!important; height: 70px; resize: none;" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Message"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="wigdet_input_box" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_Message_Send" runat="server" Text="SEND" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Width="50%" OnClick="btn_Message_Send_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <!-- CONTACT INFORMATION -->
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <!--<div class="container col-md-3" style="margin-top: 0px; position: relative; top:0px">-->
                <%--<div class="" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-left:0px; max-width: 240px; width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;">--%>
                <div class="sidebar-sticky3">
                    <div class="panel-main panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="font-size: 15px; color: #444; font-weight: bold;">AGENT INFORMATION</div>
                        <hr style="width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body"">
                            <%--<div class="agent-photo">
                                <img src="/images/agent_face.jpg" width="80" alt="Agent" style="float: left;" />
                            </div>--%>
                            <div class="contact-info" style="text-align: center; color: #444; font-size: 14px;">
                                <%--<img src="/images/agent_face.jpg" width="150" alt="Agent" />--%>
                                <h5>Contact Number: </h5><asp:Label ID="lbl_ListingContactPhone" runat="server" Text="none"></asp:Label>
                                <h5>E-mail Address: </h5><asp:Label ID="lbl_ListingContactEmail" runat="server" Text="none"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var el = jQuery('#sidebar');
      top_offset = jQuery('#sidebar').offset().top - 60;
      var box_height = el.height();

      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var bottom_offset = jQuery(document).height() - scroll_top - box_height;
        var new_top_offset = jQuery(document).height() - box_height - 100;

        if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (bottom_offset > 180))  {
          el.css('top', scroll_top - top_offset);
        }
        else if ((scroll_top > top_offset) && (bottom_offset < 181)) {
          el.css('top', new_top_offset);
        }
        else {
          el.css('top', '');
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: The code snippet doesn't work at all, and it's quite some code to go through

Comment: @BrianH. I know.. theres's so much other codes that goes with it that this isn't everthing either >.<

Comment: try reducing it to the minimal code necesary to actually reproduce your problem, otherwise you may as well add no code at all to the question. this process might even help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you are using `position: fixed;` If you tell the element that is positioned with fixed, you are setting it to be positioned fixed relative to the viewport and it will not move from there. Also, It is better to position them like this:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

It is better with top, right, bottom and left then with margins. I guess that if you want when scrolling down to change behaviour of fixed positioned element, you should consider using javascript for that.